# Why won't my multer file uploads to AWS s3 work?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I was able to get my files to upload locally but am struggling to get it on AWS S3 Buckets. I'm receiving generic **Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client** errors after submitting a request. The request isn't making it to the `createDoucment` middleware so I'm pretty certain something is wrong with `uploadFile`, but I'm at a loss for how debug this.
All of the guides that I have found online are using the (soon to be deprecated) SDKv2 and I'm trying to use V3.

controller:

```
const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: "myid",
    secretAccessKey: "mykey",
  },
  region: "us-east-2",
});
const s3Storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: "mybucket",
  acl: "public-read",
  metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, { fieldname: file.fieldname });
  },
  key: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now().toString());
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: s3Storage,
});
exports.uploadFile = upload.single("file");
exports.createDocument = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newDoc = await Model.create({
    title: req.body.title,
    file: req.file.filename,
  });
  res.status(201).json({
    status: "success",
    data: { data: newDoc },
  });
});
```

router:

```
router.route("/").post(uploadFile, createDocument);
```

Comment: put it after route handler `router.use((err, req, res, next) => { console.error(err); if(!req.headersSent) res.status(500).end(); });`

Comment: See Multer's [error handling](https://github.com/expressjs/multer?tab=readme-ov-file#error-handling) documentation for debugging hints

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it works after removing the `acl: "public-read"` line since I didn't have acl configured in my bucket